# Databinding RelativeSource alternative

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, coding-style

A lot of times I have this situation:

DataGrid with its own DataContext and DataGridTemplateColumns in which I need to access properties from CurrentItem and from DataGrid DataContext. So I end up writing tons of `{Binding DataContext.Something, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}}`

Is there any more beautiful or at least less code solution?

Comment: Might exists a place in your XAML that let you centralize the "RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}", so you only write the "DataContext.Something" or even just "Something" on the rest of the bindings?

Comment: I would like to find that place. :)

Answer (score 0):

The DataGrid is an ItemsControl and each item displayed has its DataContext set to the item it's displaying.  So clearly you can have a nice simple binding within a DataGridXXXColumn, e.g.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
```

But as you point out to get to the DataContext of the DataGrid you need to use a relative source binding.  This may seem like a lot of Xaml, but I would suggest that this is what you should do.

The only way I can think of making the Xaml simpler is to have each item in the collection have a reference back to the parent view model, so that you could bind directly like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Parent.SomeProperty}" Header="???" />
```

It's a solution but perhaps not a sensible one.